# Accessing the response text for JSONP. Flattening multiple objects to text

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I am pulling some JSONP to retrieve data to plug into highcharts...

```
$(function() {

  $.getJSON("http://xxxx.xxxxx&?callback=?", function(json){

  var data = json;
  var options = {
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime'
    },
    series: [{
      data: []
    }]
  }
  Highcharts.each(data, function(p, i) {
    for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
      options.series[0].data.push(
        [p[i].timeBucket, parseFloat(p[i].errors)]
      );
    }
  });

  $('#container').highcharts(options);
});
});
```

The data structure, when viewed through Firebug, is (example)....

```
[[{"timeBucket": XXXXXX, "errors": 10}],[{"timeBucket": XXXXXX, "errors": 30}],[{"timeBucket": XXXXXX, "errors": 20}]] ......
```

The structure as shown in Firebug is 10 objects which is true but for the life of me, I just can't get it parsed.

As a result, nothing happens.

What I did do was curl the response and saved it as "data.json" and changed my code accordingly...

```
$.getJSON("data.json", function(json){
```

It works like a champ! When I console.log the typeof I do get "Object" ( singular), so it appears I need to somehow flatten all of those 10 objects into just one and have no idea how to do it.

I have tried JSON.stringify and no luck, I have tried JSON.stringify(json) and then JSON.parse(json)

When I see the Response Text in Firebug, it's exactly what I am looking for. Anyone know how I can modify my code to use that tantalizing and needed response Text instead of the 10 object code?

Comment: So you want to have 1 array of objects?

Comment: Try this: `var data = json[0];` instead of `var data = json;`

Comment: Thanks guys! None of this works. I'll just have to use canned data until I have time to pick over this. Although ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ is on target, 1 array of objects is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jQuery.map](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to remap it so your objects are in one array.

> Description: Translate all items in an array or object to new array of items.

So you would have to replace `var data = json;` with

```
var data = $.map(json,function(x,i){
  return x[0];
});
```

That will give you the `[{},{},{}]` format which you can access in your loop like

```
 $.each(data, function(i,p) {
      options.series[0].data.push(
        [p.timeBucket, parseFloat(p.errors)]
      )
  });
```

Or if you want to keep the original loop you can do

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  options.series[0].data.push(
     [data[i].timeBucket, parseFloat(data[i].errors)]
  );
}
```

```js
var x = [[{"timeBucket": 111, "errors": 10}],[{"timeBucket": 222, "errors": 30}],[{"timeBucket": 333, "errors": 20}]];

var data = $.map(x,function(x,i){
  return x[0];
});
$('#results').html(JSON.stringify(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='results'>
```